# Run monero only in LAN

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli

I'm want to run monerod only on my LAN.  I don't want it communicate with the official blockchain.  I followed [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9868/run-monero-only-in-local-network) except that I replaced the localhost IP with my IP:

```
./monerod --stagenet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir node1 \
  --p2p-bind-ip 192.168.1.23 --p2p-bind-port 48080 --rpc-bind-port 48081 \
  --zmq-rpc-bind-port 48082 --add-exclusive-node 192.168.1.23:38080

./monerod --stagenet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir node2 --p2p-bind-ip \
  192.168.1.23 --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --confirm-external-bind \
  --add-exclusive-node 192.168.1.23:48080
```

When I run monero-wallet-cli from a difference machine, I get this error:

```
monero-wallet-cli.exe --stagenet --daemon-address 192.168.1.23:48081 --log-level 0 \
--wallet-file test
...
Warning: using an untrusted daemon at 192.168.1.23:48081, privacy will be lessened
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: 192.168.1.23:48081. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
```

If I pass `--trusted-daemon` I don't get the warning, but I still get the error.

I am able to connect to 192.168.1.23:48081 if I run a webserver on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have started the nodes (monerod) with `--stagenet`, you also need to start the wallet (monero-wallet-cli) with `--stagenet`.

**UPDATE** (question edited)

It looks like both your nodes are on the same machine (192.168.1.23) so just run them like:

```
./monerod --stagenet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir node1 \
  --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --p2p-bind-port 48080 \
  --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:38080 \
  --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --rpc-bind-port 48081 --confirm-external-bind

./monerod --stagenet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir node2 \
  --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1  --p2p-bind-port 38080 \
  --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:48080
```

Then on you wallet machine:

```
monero-wallet-cli.exe --stagenet --daemon-address 192.168.1.23:48081 \
  --log-level 0 --wallet-file test
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that!  I still get the same behavior, though. Updated question.

Comment: You are trying to connect the wallet to node1 port 48081 but that node is not specifying a rpc bind address.

Comment: To be clear, if you started your nodes exactly like in the [linked question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9868/run-monero-only-in-local-network) and just changed the wallet line to `monero-wallet-cli --stagenet --daemon-host 192.168.1.23` it would have worked also.